# Deleting Identity IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have ID column, which is a primary key and Identity is set to TRUE, inserting each row should increment my ID. My question is, if I have 100 rows and a function (somewhere in the code) to select random row (rand(1,101)), how to deal with a situation, when I delete a row and random function fails if the one was selected. I could manage this exception in the code, but wonder if there is a way in SQL to fill these deleted row gaps with continues IDs.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which flavour of SQL / RDBMS you are asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing SQL Server because of "Identity"

Use `TOP 100.. ROW_NUMBER()` instead to generate 100 contiguous values and filter on *that* value.

Or use `TOP 1..ORDER BY NEWID()` to choose a random row.

Internal IDENTITY values have no meaning except as a surrogate key. Note an INSERT fail also increments the IDENTITY value, not just deletes.

Comment: +1 for both solutions. I <3 `ROW_NUMBER()` and `ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: I know it's generally accepted as OK (due to the lack of any alternative) but ordering by NEWID() is weird. +1 regardless.